# How can I get the console output in Angular webpage?

Tags: python, django, angular

I have a Django project which is using Angular as frontend. I have a button which on clicking is scanning the tables in the database. I have some print statements views.py file which is printing the scanned results constantly in the IDE console. I want that output in the webpage. I want that live printing of the console output in the frontend. Can any one know how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using server sent events. python can push these console logs to the frontend. Not a expert of python so giving a link below to how to send server side events from python to frontend

https://medium.com/code-zen/python-generator-and-html-server-sent-events-3cdf14140e56

In frontend you can listen to url exposed and as soon as server will push any message on this stream frontend can receive it and push it into component's array and can display over ui.

for frontend code, i am giving a minimal example below :-

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SseService {
  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) {}
  getServerSentEvent(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const eventSource = this.getEventSource(url);
      eventSource.onmessage = event => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
          observer.next(event);
        });
      };
      eventSource.onerror = error => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
          observer.error(error);
        });
      };
    });
  }
  private getEventSource(url: string): EventSource {
    return new EventSource(url);
  }
}
```

you can susbcribe to getServerSentEvent in above method and can continuously receive new messages, which is in your case your console logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the following function with the information needed to be displayed.

```
addItem(val:any) {
   let node = document.createElement("li")
   let textnode = document.createTextNode(val)
   node.appendChild(textnode)
   document.getElementById("output").appendChild(node) 
}
```

Make sure to have an element with the id="output".